# Customer data organisation tool

Tags: database, cloud-service, address-book

I'm looking for a tool, that stores our contact data from our customers/ clients.

**Current situation:**
Currently we store everything in an excel spreadsheet. With columns for: First Name, Last Name, Address, Zip Code, Email, Language (to name a few).

This is pretty stressful to maintain and organize (duplicates, from formatting etc.).

**So what we need:**
A piece of software that can store our customer data with a simple "fill in process". Basically an interface to enter all the data. We should be able to add custom fields, so not stuck to the basic "Address, Email, Name" stuff but add our own fields like "Customertype" for example. It should be in the cloud or selfhosted, but can also be local if there is no other way.
Also, free would be good, but let's be real, I don't think that is possible, so paid would be ok.
To use our data we need the option to export the data as csv. A CRM isn't needed, as simple as possible.

Actually it's just a database with a visual interface to input data.

**Summary:**

- Export as csv possible
- Lightweight, no CRM or other stuff needed that make the interface and usability clunky
- Cloudbased in best case
- Best case free, but paid is possible
- database like application with userinterface

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [airtable](https://airtable.com/). It is basically a free table with a nice interface.

They have a free plan too. In the free plan you can store up to 1,200 records per base.
There are some other features, so it might not be quite as lightweight as you need. But definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

[Ragic](https://www.ragic.com) can meet all your requirements.  It is a no-code, customizable database that looks like Excel but is much easier to manage and format. You can add/delete fields in the sheets with ease. It is cloudbased and mobile connected, so your customers can fill out their information once you share the access link. You can customize up to 3 sheets for free!

(Disclosure: I work for Ragic)